# friend's birthday in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have written the following code to get a friend's birthday but I get null in the birthday field. Please tell me where the problem is.

```
 String fqlQuery = "select uid, name, pic_square, birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    AccessToken myToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(session.getAccessToken(), 
            new Date(2013,6,24), new Date(10000000),
            AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NATIVE, Arrays.asList("friends_birthday"));
    //String token = "CAACEdEose0cBADB1tGwC5OA56v51uNfdMWhe6MliCaJLZBsZBzQdNobdpxyST0Ml10pwJmZBCeZCZC3RcYGSUfDEie9tTZBqMnPmOsJ7lpZBp197u9yZBUpXlDBGOQFHqwNbHwErAVRWXPi6e0WXL5hZBgDREFfZBlwEXGLWn8w407SgZDZD";
    Log.e("AccessToken",myToken.toString());
    params.putString("access_token",myToken.getToken());

    Request request = new Request(session, 
        "/fql", 
        params, 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        new Request.Callback(){ 
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.i("",response.toString());
            }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

If some of your friends birthday's are available and some aren't it's because the latter friends decided not to provide it. If all friends are not available ensure you have `friends_birthday` permission

`graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?fields=friends_birthday`